# DAPPER is Not Working Properly. I am Newbie to this Framework

Tags: c#, dapper

For simplicity, I removed some Methods in Accounts Class, some lines in Display Method and displayed only required.

```
    class Accounts
    {
        public int AccountNo { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public int Balance { get; set; }
    }       

    public void Dispaly()
    {     
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
        conn.Open();
        var res = conn.Query<Accounts>("select * from Accounts").ToList();
        foreach (Accounts ac in res)
             {
                Console.WriteLine("Account No : " + ac.AccountNo);
                Console.WriteLine("Name : " + ac.Firstname);
                Console.WriteLine("Balance : " + ac.Balance);
            }
        conn.Close();
        return;
        }
     }
```

My Table schema
[image: Table Schema]

When I Call Display Method, DAPPER is Not Mapping Balance Value Correctly from DataBase.

```
 /********************* MY OUTPUT *******************/
 Account No : 12345
 Name : SHINDE
 Balance : 0
```

NOTE: If I rename Balance Method in Accounts Class to Amount. It was working fine.
Using DAPPER, There is any relation between Method Name in my Program and Column Name in DB?

Comment: You need to show us your Accounts class and your SQL schema for the table. I'm pretty sure Dapper works OK, and something hasn't been defined right.

Comment: Remember, Dapper, without some kind of mapping between the class Accounts and the table Accounts requires exact match between the properties names and the fields names. Also check if the datatype of the properties and fields are compatible

Comment: Just out of curiosity, so that I can understand your thought process better: You really thought that Dapper should have been able to *automatically guess* that `Amount` should be mapped to `Balance`?

Answer (score 1):

With the edit, we can see that the table doesn't have a `Balance` - it has `Amount`. You will need to give it some help. You *could* rename the `Balance` property to `Amount` in your C# code, or you could use the query to tweak it, for example:

```
var res = conn.Query<Accounts>(
    "select AccountNo, FirstName, Amount as Balance from Accounts").AsList();
```

(note that `AsList` here is slightly more efficient than `ToList` - it avoids an extra few allocations; also note that you don't actually need `Open`/`Close` here - Dapper is happy to do that for you)